# Analyse requests in real-time

Tags: logstash

I have a service exporting WebSocket interface and it allows connection from Internet.

Now I need detect if the request is sent from bots.

The basic idea is -- when the request rates from certain IP address is much higher than a reasonable value, that IP address is suspectable.

Is Logstash suitable for this case? -- check the data in a very recent period.

Answer (score 0):

logstash is concerned about one event at a time.  There is a metrics{} filter that will keep track of information for you, but just as basic counts (not percentages).

I would lean towards running custom queries against elasticsearch to determine the information you need.